Did Einstein say the one-way speed-of-light is "not a fact of nature"?
If so is there a published paper or even an informal letter where he said as much?

A web search for "einstein" "speed of light" "not a fact of nature" only turns up M Slavov, "Time as an Empirical Concept in Special Relativity" (2019). Slavov cites Wesley C. Salmon, "The Philosophial Significance of the One-Way Speed of Light," Noûs 11, no. 3 (September 1977): 253‒292, at 254. Salmon wrote

From the standpoint of classical physics, as well as simple common sense, it would seem that the equality (or inequality) of the speeds in the two opposite directions is a fact of nature. [...] Einstein seems [...] to be claiming that the relation between the speeds in the two different directions is not a matter of fact at all—rather, it must be established by means of a convention.

citing Einstein's original 1905 paper, which in German said

Es ist aber ohne weitere Festsetzung nicht möglich, ein Ereignis in A mit einem Ereignis in B zeitlich zu vergleichen; wir haben bisher nur eine „A-Zeit“ und eine „B-Zeit“, aber keine für A und B gemeinsame „Zeit“ definiert. Die letztere Zeit kann nun definiert werden, indem man durch Definition festsetzt, daß die „Zeit“, welche das Licht braucht, um von A nach B zu gelangen, gleich ist der „Zeit“, welche es braucht, um von B nach A zu gelangen.

English translation by DeepL, which I think is accurate:

However, it is not possible without further definition to compare an event in A with an event in B in terms of time; so far we have only defined an "A-time" and a "B-time", but no "time" common to A and B. The latter time can now be defined by establishing by definition that the "time" it takes for light to travel from A to B is equal to the "time" it takes to travel from B to A.

I think the wording "[not] a fact of nature" is Salmon's, but Einstein did write something to that effect.

An alternative to using DeepL would have been to use the translation that is available on wikisource: On the electrodynamics of moving bodies In this particular case the DeepL translation seems to be quite adequate. Actually, in the DeepL translation the italics font for the words durch Definition is transcribed, whereas the corresponding words in the wikisource version are not in italics font.

Einstein published five papers in 1905.  The given quote seems to be from the fourth, about special relativity.  I'm having trouble reconciling that with the description "Einstein's original 1905 paper."  His first 1905 paper was about the photoelectric effect, which was also the subject for which he was awarded the Nobel prize, so that was not inconsequential.

@JohnBollinger given the question is about relativity, I'd assume the paper about relativity was meant, not some other one. But feel free to suggest an edit to make it clearer.

What Einstein means here is pretty well explained in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pTn6Ewhb27k . Making the speed of light equal in all directions is a convenient convention. You can make it 1/2c in one direction and infinite in the other and all observation would be equally well explained. Since multiple conventions give identical results we cannot tell which one is "nature" and which one isn't. In fact, the question would be meaningless.

Einstein explicitly  establishes this convention in his 1905 paper "on the electrodynamics of moving bodies"

@Cleonis I didn't use the popular Perrett/Jeffery translation (though Salmon uses it) because it actually mistranslates this passage (possibly because they misread "nun" as "nur"). I didn't know about the one on Wikisource, but it also seems a bit iffy, not only omitting the italics as you said but also the scare quotes. I think I'd rather keep the DeepL translation, but I don't know much German and may be wrong.

@Hilmar That video has prompted dozens of questions from confused viewers on the Physics SE and Astronomy SE since it was posted in 2020. In my opinion he doesn't understand Einstein's point at all, and the video has misled millions of people. I wrote about it in this answer.

@benrg.  Sorry, but I'm not sure what your point here is.  I don't see much of a difference between your answer and what's in the video and I don't understand what exactly is "misleading " here.. I'm a native German speaker and the original quote is indeed correct and the translation feels reasonably accurate to me. It boils down to: "you can only measure the speed of light for a roundtrip and how much time you attribute to the outbound vs the return is arbitrary. Hence we might as well make it equal, but there is nothing more "natural" about this choice than any other.

@Hilmar About the Veritasium video. That video offers a muddled exposition, in my opinion. The point he is trying to make is understandable only for people who have already absorbed the subject. About what I think is problematic: the issue of conventionality of relativity comes up exclusively in the context of relativity of simultaneity. On the other hand: in the context of newtonian space and time there is no relativity of simultaneity, therefore no conventionality of simultaneity. In the video the concept of Minkowski spacetime is touched on implicitly, but that is not enough.
